# APL find frequency of elements in a matrix

Tags: matrix, frequency, apl

I have this piece of code

```
((⍳3)∘.+(⍳2))
```

which generates the following matrix

```
2 3 
3 4 
4 5
```

I want to find the occurrence of each unique element in the result i.e occurrence of 2,3,4,5 in the result.

I tried using "∘.=" with the matrix itself and then reshaping such that elements of each sub matrix is transformed into a row 
using

```
6 6⍴ ((⍳3)∘.+(⍳2))∘.=((⍳3)∘.+(⍳2))
```

which gives the following result

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 for 2
0 1 1 0 0 0 for 3
0 1 1 0 0 0 for 3
0 0 0 1 1 0 for 4
0 0 0 1 1 0 for 4
0 0 0 0 0 1 for 5
```

as you can see it still contains the sum for duplicate items, and I'm lost as of now. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `∘.=` between the unique elements in the matrix and a flat vector of all elements, like:

```
      m ← ((⍳3)∘.+(⍳2))
      (∪,m) ∘.= ,m
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Then just do `+/` on it to get the frequencies of `∪,m`

```
      +/ (∪,m) ∘.= ,m
1 2 2 1
      ∪,m
2 3 4 5
```

(Tested on GNU APL.)

Comment: Worked like a charm on Dyalog APL also. Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest embedding it in a dynamic function which is more "dyalog-style" ;-)   {+/ (∪⍵) ∘.= ⍵},m

Answer (score 0):

*Dyalog APL version 14.0* has the `⌸` Key operator exactly for this, you just need to ravel your data:

```
      {≢⍵}⌸ ,((⍳3)∘.+(⍳2))
1 2 2 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBLmP2iZoaDzq3Wys@ahjhp42iGmkqclV/ahz0aPerbWPenbo5AIA)

You can even use the left argument of `⌸`'s operand function to create a table:

```
      {⍺,≢⍵}⌸ ,((⍳3)∘.+(⍳2))
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBLmP2iZoaDzq3Wys@ahjhp42iGmkqclV/ah3l86jzkWPerfWPurZoZMLAA)